# how to handle delete and backspace in content-editable if content-editable have span and cursor is outside span and in p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Following is my example and it works on Chrome but in Internet Explorer it is not working .

> **What is my issues**

1) **when cursor is in span node and if I have press delete it adds `<br>` tag**

2) **If cursor is outside span and in `<p>` tag it won't delete span tag and cursor remains at that position**

3) **I dont want to delete complete span.**

> **What I Want**

- **when I press delete or backspace I should check where the cursor is..?**
- **If cursor is at last means outside span and in p tag it should not add `<br>` tags on delete and should allow to backspace text inside `<span>`**.

```html
<div contenteditable = "true">

<h2 style=\"margin: 0in -6.65pt 0pt 2in;\"><span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"font-size: 10.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 10.0pt;\"><font face=\"Book Antiqua\">Mr PQR</font></span></h2><br><p style=\"margin: 0in -6.65pt 0pt 2in; text-indent: 0.5in;\"><span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"font-size: 10.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 10.0pt;\"><strong><font face=\"Book Antiqua\">63 Yrs M</font></strong></span></p><br><p style=\"margin: 0in -6.65pt 0pt 2in; text-indent: 0.5in;\"><span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"font-size: 10.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 10.0pt;\"><strong><font face=\"Book Antiqua\">Dr. ABC</font></strong></span></p><br><p style=\"margin: 0in -6.65pt 0pt 2in; text-indent: 0.5in;\"><span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"font-size: 10.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 10.0pt;\"><strong><font face=\"Book Antiqua\">04.05.2003<span style=\"mso-tab-count: 1;\">&nbsp; </span><span style=\"mso-spacerun: yes;\">&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style=\"mso-tab-count: 2;\">&nbsp; </span></font></strong></span></p><p style=\"margin: 0in -6.65pt 0pt 2.5in; text-indent: 0.5in;\"><span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"font-size: 10.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 10.0pt;\"><strong><font face=\"Book Antiqua\">&nbsp;</font></strong></span></p><p style=\"margin: 0in -6.65pt 0pt 2.5in; text-indent: 0.5in;\"><span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"font-size: 10.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 10.0pt;\"><strong><font face=\"Book Antiqua\">&nbsp;</font></strong></span></p><p style=\"margin: 0in -6.65pt 0pt 2.5in; text-indent: 0.5in;\"><span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"font-size: 10.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 10.0pt;\"><strong><font face=\"Book Antiqua\">&nbsp;</font></strong></span></p><h4 style=\"margin: 0in -6.65pt 0pt 0in; text-indent: 0in;\"><u><font face=\"Book Antiqua\"><b style=\"mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;\"><span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"font-size: 10.5pt; text-decoration: none; mso-bidi-font-size: 10.0pt; text-underline: none;\"></span></b><b style=\"mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;\"><span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"font-size: 10.5pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 10.0pt;\">MRI STERNO CLAVICULAR JOINTS</span></b></font></u></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to be more descriptive and provide a clutter free code.
[Please refer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think It is more precise and descriptive